# How to get current time in Nintex workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I'm using infopath 2013 form with nintex 2013 workflow.

My current requirement is one form is requested by requester. The same form will expired at 11.59 pm on same day requested(form at any status).

methods I try

```
1. get remaining minutes from form requested date time. and configure the 
  renaming minutes in Pause for using parallel action field in workflow but it pause the entire workflow
```

how to get current time in for loop or anything at 11.59pm i need to end the workflow automatically.

plz suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a "Date and time" variable in your workflow. Then, configure an action "Set a variable" like this:

- First dropdown box => your variable
- Second dropdown box (Equals to) => **Workflow Context**
- Third dropdown box => **Current Time**

Finally, you'll can use this variable in your loop.

I hope it helps! :)